# Symlink everywhere

Tags: command-line, vim, symlink, vi

Is there any way for me to symlink a particular file so that it appears in every directory on the system?

So if I symlink `/tmp/scratch`

No matter where I am I can type `vi scratch`?

Comment: You could create a command for Vi that if you type in `vi +scratch` it will automatically open /tmp/scratch. Its much more maintainable.

Comment: @sparticvs If you could expand this comment into an answer with actual vimscript code, I think it would be really useful.

Comment: `find / -type d` will find every directory on your system. However if adding this symlink everywhere does not break something, you will still regret it. (with great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: why not just do `alias scratch='vi /my/path/scratch.txt'` then when you run `scratch` anywhere on the system, it will open `/my/path/scratch.txt`?

Answer (score 7):

Since Joseph R wanted me to expand, I will.  If you use VIM (because that's what I know more than Vi) you can add this to your `~/.vimrc` file.

```
if @% == "scratch"
    silent edit /tmp/scratch
endif
```

Tada, now you have scratch everywhere!

Comment: @JosephR. thanks for making me do this, because now I have this in my vimrc and I have found it to be REALLY useful.

Answer (score 4):

A more robust solution would be to use an alias in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias viscrtch='vi /tmp/scratch'
```

This way `viscrtch` can be used to edit `/tmp/scratch` from anywhere within the filesystem.

If you want the ability to add command line arguments, use a shell function instead:

```
viscrtch(){ vi "$@" /tmp/scratch; }
```

Call it as

```
viscrtch your_options_here
```

Even if you find a way to symlink one file to every directory in the system, I discourage you from doing it: it's neither maintainable nor practical.

Comment: Alternatively you could do `alias scratchpad='vi /tmp/scratch'` and then you have a new command. Same as above just renamed something that you will probably remember.

Answer (score 0):

As others noted, it is probably not the best solution, but here is a way to link in all directories beneath the current.

```
#!/bin/bash

lnfile="/tmp/scratch"
for Dir in $(find ./* -type d);
do
    ln -s $lnfile $Dir
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`find / -type d -exec ln -s -T /tmp/scratch scratch {} \;`